# Passing a listener through a chain of Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, callback, listener

I want to be able to define a listener (an Activity, Fragment, etc) and be able to pass it through any number of nested Fragments before I decide to finally invoke the callback. That way it can call `callback.someFunction()` and it doesn't need to know what `Activity` or `Fragment` that callback is attached to.

Right now it seems, though, that there is no good way to send a listener through a bunch of `Fragments`. I initially considered passing it through the constructors, but then the listener reference would be nulled out on a configuration change like a screen rotation.

I then considered the `onAttach()` methods, but these only give you access to the `context` of the base `Activity` which doesn't necessarily do what I want, either.

I also considered passing the listeners in through `newInstance()` (which is normally how you save arguments passed into `Fragments` because the contents of `getArguments()` survives configuration changes via the `Bundle`), but I could not see any good way to save the listener in the argument `Bundle`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is recreate everything when a configuration change happens or when the activity is re-created and its instance state restored...which is the same for that matter...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acitivyt_layout);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        //1. restore instance state here
        savedInstanceState.getString("whatever");

       //2. try to find the fragment 
       Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT TAG");

        //3. make sure the fragment is correctly set up if already loaded
        if(f != null){
            ((ConcreteFragmentType)f).setListener(your_listener);
            //bring the fragment to the front or show it using the fragment manager
        }
        //4. or else add a brand-new instance
        else{
                ConcreteFragmentType c = ConcreteFragmentType.newInstance();
                c.setListener(your_listener);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, c)
                        .commit();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for based on my question

Comment: @user6935095 the answer demostrates how to restore instance state in a fragment after the activity is re-created. What exactly did I miss?